# Laravel Research based Project

Tags: php, laravel

I am a studdent of CSE . I want a project or thesis on laravel (final thesis/project)  which have many research . You have any idea about such type of project on laravel ?

Comment: Maybe you should take another look at the [tour]. This question is far too broad.

Comment: @Nazmul Hossain if someone has idea why he/she will share it with you? You have to think and create idea yourself. However you can take a look on codecanyon.net projects and just get idea how other developers are developing projects.Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @Iftikharuddin

Comment: Good luck @NazmulHossain